# https proxy using okhttp3

Tags: java, okhttp

I am using okhttp3 and trying to see how do I pass userId & pswd to authenticate with proxy server that accepts only HTTPS protocol. I already saw exmaple over SO & on other sites(link below) but they don't have HTTPS protocol.

https://botproxy.net/docs/how-to/okhttpclient-proxy-authentication-how-to/

Can anyone please tell me how to use HTTPS protocol to call proxy server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not officially supported but there is a workaround.

https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6561

```
Authenticator proxyAuthenticator = new Authenticator() {
    @Override public Request authenticate(Route route, Response response) throws IOException {
        String credential = Credentials.basic(username, password);
        return response.request().newBuilder().header("Proxy-Authorization", credential).build();
    }
};

OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .proxy(new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort)))
        .proxyAuthenticator(proxyAuthenticator);
        .socketFactory(new DelegatingSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault()))
        .build();
```

Comment: Thanks.. It worked for me.

Comment: `DelegatingSocketFactory` deprecated, what replacement?

Comment: Copy that class into your project if you need. https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/ee9ebba20a39e6e4cdd78cb74f488728e49de942/okhttp-testing-support/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/DelegatingSocketFactory.kt#L27

Comment: Are you importing `Proxy` with magic? Where's the import statement!

Comment: import java.net.Proxy